# Line 39 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Enemy

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

First I had no compiler errors but my for EACH was not working

```
for each( var enemy:Enemy in army ) 
{
   enemy.moveDownAbit();
}
```

I replaced the for EACH with just for and I have been getting this error.

and I have no idea how to fix it as I am new to AS3.

This is my Enemy.as

```
public class Enemy extends MovieClip
{
    public function Enemy(startX:Number, startY:Number)
    {
        x=startX;
        y=-startY;
    }

    public function moveDownAbit(): void
    {
        y=y+3;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code with declaration and usage of `army`?

Comment: `army = new Array();`
   `var newEnemy = new Enemy(100,-15);`
   `army.push( newEnemy );`
   `addChild( newEnemy );`

Comment: The original `for each` loop seems to be correct. Works in my tests. Can you explain what wasn't working?

Answer (score 0):

If you just replaced for-each with for it is not enough.

The following sample

```
for var enemy:Enemy in army ) 
{
   enemy.moveDownAbit();
}
```

Will indeed try to read all the "properties" of Army and not loop through the list of them.
This is helpful when you want for example to print the properties/values of an object
Ex:

```
class Person
{
   public var name:String = "Object name";
   public var age:int = 20;
}


function doForLoop()
{
   var myPers:Person = new Person();

   // here your loop 
   for (var prop:String in myPers)
   {
        trace(prop+" = "+myPers[prop]);
   }

   // ---- previus loop will trace:
   // name = Object name
   // age = 20 

   // whet you actually need is
   for(var i:int = 0 ; i < army.length ; i++)
   {
       var enemy:Enemy = army[i] as Enemy;

       // do your work now
       enemy.moveDownAbit();
    }
}
```

Hope explanation helps.